# FaceBook Interests field with asp.net

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I,m using facebookClient to get Interest data of user from face book

i,m able to get the data  which looks like

{"data":[{"name":"Lean Startup","category":"Product/service","id":"387431575880","created_time":"2012-04-10T10:00:38+0000"},{"name":"Enterpreneur","category":"Interest","id":"376510765740","created_time":"2012-04-10T10:00:38+0000"},{"name":"Aquariums","category":"Interest","id":"111987498819971","created_time":"2012-04-10T10:00:37+0000"},{"name":"Creating websites","category":"Society/culture","id":"153238868040287","created_time":"2012-04-10T10:00:37+0000"}],"paging":{"next":"https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=interests,email&access_token=AAAtnZB65tZB7tsBAMr3M4ZAaUHypodxgIR9kSop3g6SfbaaKZBBB5K8MLLdT0bzJhwh1PPtK7ZCFJWOZB5vVV36haGkpxV2CoAcUlIl13ZBWOwZDZD&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=153238868040287"}}

how can i cast it to keyvalue pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dynamic result = fb.Get("me/interests");
var jsonArray= ((Facebook.JsonArray)result.data);
var nvDict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
foreach(dynamic obj in jsonArray)
{
    nvDict.Add(obj.id, obj.name);
}
```

Could you just keep the object as a Facebook.JsonObject rather than converting it into a Dictionary?